# What does * 0x3e8 mean in C# timeout calculation?

Tags: c#, timeout, httpwebrequest

I am sending a httpwebrequest with C# API and got some timeout error. During troubleshooting I see the following code

```
timeout = timeout * 0x3e8;
```

What does `0x3e8` mean here? Why do we might want to multiple by this number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This hex `0x3e8` is a `1000` in decimal form. So that line is an equivalent of:

```
timeout = timeout * 1000;
```

As @user2888973 guessed, we might want to multiply by it to get milliseconds number from seconds.

Comment: so if I pass timeout = 5, then the actual timeout would be 5000 in the unit of ms?

Comment: @user2210021 no doubt

Comment: I guess That would be the meaning... time is given in seconds instead of milisecods